# How can I automatically run 2 python scripts at the same time in a virtual environment when booting up the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, autostart

Note: I'm new to everything so bare with me.

I'm using a RPi 4B with Buster. My goal is to automatically run 2 python scripts at the same time when the pi first boots up. Both scripts are in a virtual environment. The first script is called `sensor.py` which basically uses an ultrasonic distance sensor to continuously calculate distances between the sensor and an object. The other is an object recognition script from Tensorflow Lite called `TFLite_detection_webcam.py` that identifies objects from a camera feed. I can't use rc.local for autorunning because the object recognition script uses a picamera feed as an input, which rc.local doesn't support. So my preferred option is using autostart. I was able to successfully get the sensor.py script to autorun  by issuing this in the terminal: `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and adding this to it: `/home/pi/tflite1/tflite1-env/bin/python3 /home/pi/tflite1/sensor.py`. In this case, tflite1-env is the virtual environment being activated. However, I don't know how to get the second script to run. To run it regularly, I would issue the following into the terminal and the camera feed would pop up on the screen as a window.

```
cd tflite1
source tflite1-env/bin/activate
python3 TFLite_detection_webcam.py --modeldir=TFLite_model
```

I've tried to get this script to run by adding this to the autostart file: `/home/pi/tflite1/tflite1-env/bin/python3 /home/pi/tflite1/TFLite_detection_webcam.py --modeldir=TFLite_model` but it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried to run it using shell files, but every time that I run a shell file in the autostart file such as adding ./launch.sh to the bottom, nothing happens. Any help getting the second script to run at the same time as the first upon startup would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use Systemd. Set up Systemd unit files in `/etc/systemd/system`, e.g.

## kitkats-sensor.unit

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/tflite1/tflite1-env/bin/python3 /home/pi/tflite1/sensor.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/tflite1/
User=pi
Group=pi
```

## kitkats-tflite.unit

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/tflite1/tflite1-env/bin/python3 /home/pi/tflite1/TFLite_detection_webcam.py --modeldir=TFLite_model
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/tflite1/
User=pi
Group=pi
```

Then enable the unit files with `systemctl enable kitkats-tflite` and `systemctl enable kitkats-sensor` (to have them autostart) and `systemctl start kitkats-tflite` (and sensor) to start them right away.

You can then see them in e.g. `systemctl`, and their logs are diverted to `journalctl`.